# ajax call in django admin pannel with custom app

Tags: django

I have created a question app and I can add the question from admin. There is one Boolean field named `is_mcq`. 
This is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from languages.models import Language
from languageversions.models import Languageversion
from experiences.models import Experience
from difficulties.models import Difficulty

class Question(models.Model):
language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
version = models.ForeignKey(Languageversion, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
experience = models.ForeignKey(Experience, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
difficulty = models.ForeignKey(Difficulty, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
question = models.TextField(blank=False)
answer = models.TextField(blank=False)
is_mcq = models.BooleanField(default=False )
mcq_answer = models.TextField(blank=True)
mcq_answer1 = models.TextField(blank=True)
mcq_answer2 = models.TextField(blank=True)
mcq_answer3 = models.TextField(blank=True)
attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Now what I want to do is: by default I want to make the hidden field for mcq_answer, mcq_answer1, mcq_answer2, mcq_answer3. if `is_mcq` is checked, then I want to show these 4 fields in the form for more answers.

I can do the jquery stuff to show more fields but I am not sure where should I do this.

Here is the code from admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('id', 'language', 'version', 'experience', 'difficulty', 'title', 'question', 'answer', 'is_mcq')
search_fields = ('language', 'experience', 'title')
list_per_page = 20


admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Comment: Please, add some line of code which can show what you have done so far.

Comment: I spaced out your question and details.  This post probably needs a bit more code (showing what you've done) to be able to get a good answer though.

Comment: I have updated the question for more clarity. Can you plz give me some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Iam not entirely sure what you are trying to do but if you want to display certain fields in a form based on a boolean maybe take a look at jqueries [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). This is more a jquery question than a django question.

Comment: I can do by jquery. But I am not sure where to do it(file path). In questions app admin.py file, I created QuestionAdmin Class:     'class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'language', 'version', 'experience', 'difficulty', 'title', 'question', 'answer', 'is_mcq')
    search_fields = ('language', 'experience', 'title')
    # list_filter = (QuestionsFilter,)
    list_per_page = 20

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)'

Now on where do I write the jQuery code? Where wiil be view file for this?

Comment: You have to integrate jquery into your website like you would on any other website. Well a bit different since you have to place it in your template or base.html or wherever the head of your website is located.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this by adding the media class(link of js file) on admin.py file like this:

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('question', 'language', 'experience', 'difficulty', 'is_mcq')
search_fields = ('question', 'language')
list_display_links = ('question',)
list_editable = ('is_mcq',)
list_per_page = 20
class Media:
    js = (
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', # jquery
            'js/admin.js',       # project static folder
        )

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

and putting the jQuery code on admin.js file like this:

```
$(function() {
if (!$('#id_is_mcq').is(':checked')) {
    $('.field-mcq_answer').hide();
    $('.field-mcq_answer1').hide();
    $('.field-mcq_answer2').hide();
    $('.field-mcq_answer3').hide();
}
$('#id_is_mcq').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.field-mcq_answer').hide();
        $('.field-mcq_answer1').hide();
        $('.field-mcq_answer2').hide();
        $('.field-mcq_answer3').hide();            
    }else{
        $('.field-mcq_answer').show();
        $('.field-mcq_answer1').show();
        $('.field-mcq_answer2').show();
        $('.field-mcq_answer3').show();           
    }
});
});
```

Hope this will help for others like me who just started on Django.